# Custom read producing garbage

Tags: c++

I'm implementing my own read function that reads content from a file into a buffer.  It successfully reads the information in the file but when I print out the information it has garbage null bytes '\00\' attached to the output.
So an output from my read could be "hi\00\00\00th\00\00\00er\00e" when reading "hi there" I have no idea what is causing this and any help is appreciated. I'm not sure if it's important or not but the '\00\' appear after 2 chars every time.

```
bool FileRead(int ptrBuffer, int bufferSize, int fid)
{
  if (bufferSize == 0)
    {
     DEBUG('p', "Cannot read zero bytes.\n");
     machine->WriteRegister(2, -2);
     return false;
    }

  char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (bufferSize +1));
  DEBUG('p', "Attempting to read %d bytes from file %d\n", bufferSize, fid);
  // Read bytes from the file.
  OpenFile* file = openFileTable[fid - FID_OFFSET];
  if (file == NULL) {
      DEBUG('p', "File does not exist!\n");
      machine->WriteRegister(2, -4);
      return false;
  }
  file->Read(buffer, bufferSize + 1);
  int len = strlen(buffer);
  DEBUG('p', "Read string %s with len %d\n", buffer, len);
  buffer[len] = '\0';
  strcpy(&machine->mainMemory[ptrBuffer], buffer);
  machine->WriteRegister(2, len-1);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This code has a lot of external dependencies we can't see.

Comment: Neither can I, I do not have direct access to these functions and cannot edit them.  However; I know for a fact that they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not null-terminating the bytes you read, and also you're ignoring how many bytes are actually read:

```
file->Read(buffer, bufferSize + 1);
```

Should be:

```
int nr = file->Read(buffer, bufferSize + 1);
if(nr > 0) {
  buffer[min(nr, bufferSize)] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am still getting the same problem with a similar change to this.

Comment: @CSjunkie The caller of your FileRead method must also null-terminate the bytes you're returning before printing them, because you're not returning the null-terminator. I'm not saying that your method SHOULD return the null-terminator, but rather that the caller should null-terminate the buffer itself before printing.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  With forcing the caller to add the '\0' I no longer get gibberish but it is cutting off the last char returned from read.  Also, when I use bufferSize = 1 it cuts off every other char, which means that read is reading bufferSize+1 chars instead of bufferSize.

Comment: I fixed the cutting off of the last char.  Thanks for the help! I changed `file->Read(buffer, bufferSize + 1);` to `file->Read(buffer, bufferSize);`

Comment: @CSjunkie Glad to help. I was going to say, your method should return the number of bytes read instead of a boolean, otherwise the caller doesn't know how many bytes were read, and doesn't know where to put the null-terminator.

Comment: The complete code is very complicated, but in short this portion can only be called by a void function and it returns its results by storing them in a register. The complete code is several directories each with a few dozen source and header files in them. That's why I can't provide definitions for many of the functions as they themselves may rely on other files, eventually relying on assembly code.

Comment: OK now I understand better. In that case you should be calling writeRegister with len, not len-1... or better yet, with nr. But I'm sure you figured that out by now.

Answer (score 2):

The following lines seem very suspect:

```
file->Read(buffer, bufferSize + 1);
int len = strlen(buffer);
buffer[len] = '\0';
```

Here you try to get the length of the buffer you read by using `strlen` which explicitly expects the string it is passed is terminated. You *then* terminate the buffer as a string. If the buffer does not contain the terminator to begin with, using the `strlen` function will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Most likely the `Read` function *returns* the length it has read (that's the usual), which means you need to use that value (and read one less character) if it's value length:

```
auto len = file->Read(buffer, bufferSize);
if (len > 0)
{
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    ... (the rest of the code) ...
}
```

Also, do this terminating *before* you try to print it.

Comment: Thanks, I made this change and am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In the line:  `char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (bufferSize +1));` you are attempting to allocate bufferSize number of POINTERs to character.
 What you really want to allocate is:

`char *buffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (bufferSize +1));`

or more simply:

`char *buffer = (char *)malloc(bufferSize + 1);`

Edit: 
Btw, not familiar with the "OpenRead" class etc, so not sure what those reads do under the hood etc. Not sure if it has a return value or not.

Another thing to watch for is that assuming that the ->read method is anything like expected where it null-terminates the string, then strlen will indeed give you the amount of bytes in the string.

What you need to ensure is that the target of your strcpy has room for the buffer contents. A safer copy may be to use strncpy(dst, src, len) call instead.

Comment: Thank you, I tested it and read does return the number of bytes read, and I made the change you suggested as well as the one suggested by the other two answers and still get the \00\'s

Comment: In the original code, you would be allocating:<br><br> (bufferSize + 1) * 4  [For 32bit systems)<br><br>(bufferSize +1) * 8 [For 64bit systems]

Comment: Hmmm... well, next step then is to put in a print loop right after your `file->Read` line to see if it populates buffer as expected.  Do you know how to use gdb or whatever debugger is available on your platform?   Lastly, did you try the simpler:   `char *buffer = new char[bufferSize +1];` call?

Comment: ... Wait a second!   Do you know what this "file->Read" does? Any documentation - I now suspect maybe it is (in addition to other issues people mentioned like the termination/strlen above) that the read reads in UNICODE bytes?  I am not very familiar with them but I am aware that that is one of a couple "multibyte" character sets. Perhaps that may be a lead.   What platform are you running on and under what OS version and compiler (latter probably unimportant)

Comment: If the OS is Linux, try "vi" on the file to see what it looks like, or better yet a util like hexedit to see raw bytes in the source file.

Comment: I did try the simpler call and got the same results.  The code for file->Read is written in assembly so I cannot tell what format it is reading in.  As far as the OS goes this is intended to be kernal code and isn't running on an OS.

Comment: using "vi" shows the same output but with '^@' instead of '\00'.  The host system I am developing on is linux

Comment: OK - then it does appear that you have GIGO until you find out if you have to treat the file contents as a particular "locale" or encoding. I am just not conversant enough with non-ASCII text. This is again, presuming that the file was not incorrectly written TO (GIGO) and is instead in a non-ASCII format...